# Вычислить сумму заштрихованных элементов матрицы показанных на рисунке

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define n 7
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int K[n][n];
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            K[i][j] = rand() % 201 - 100;
            cout << " " << K[i][j] << " ";


        }
        cout << endl << "\n";
    }

}
```

Из двумерного массива с рандомными, числами найти сумму заштрихованных элементов матрицы.

Comment: И чё? тупо сложить...

Comment: вы имеете ввиду каждый элемент матрицы сложить вот так ?K[0][0]+K[0][1]...

Comment: Конечно. Задание же дополнительно ничем не ограничивает и ничего не требует.

Comment: да но мой препод так не думает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "N: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int matrix[n][n];
    int sum = 0;

    int col_start = 0;
    int col_finish = n - 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            matrix[row][col] = std::rand() % 201 - 100;
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << matrix[row][col];

            if (col_start <= col_finish)
            {
                if (col >= col_start && col <= col_finish)
                {
                    sum += matrix[row][col];
                }
            }

            if (row == n - 1)
            {
                sum += matrix[row][col];
            }
        }
        col_start++;
        col_finish--;

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "SUM: " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


// N: 7

// -59  76   3  69 -26 -54 -79
// -88 -72  43 -23 -95  66  44
//  12 -11  81 -17 -97 -91 -70
//  32 -17  53  -9  21  35 -77
// -80  97 -80 -82  -2 -19 -40
// -87  40  69  51 -55  61  -7
//  67  83  86 -59 -34 -27  13

// SUM: -64
```

Comment: спасибо огромное очень помогли